# Reuse a ToolStripMenu for a ToolStrip or a ContextMenuStrip?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, menu

In my application, I have a ToolStripMenu (File, Edit, Notes), a ToolStrip right above my work area and a context menu for the work area itself. Now the Notes ToolStripMenu, the ToolStrip and the ContextMenuStrip all have the same content that performs the same actions. I was wondering, is there an elegant way to just design the ToolStripMenu and have the other two "mirror" it's function and content instead of rewriting everything 3 times? I saw that all 3 controls use ToolStripItems and ToolStripItemCollections and as such I would think this would be quite easy to do, but the properties are mostly read only, and if I try to loop through one's item to add them to the other, they are removed from the initial owner, and there are no Clone method for ToolStripItems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method that re-uses your items, actions, etc...

```
public MainForm()
{
    //in your constructor, create all your common methods, actions, etc and save them to private vars

    //Then in your form:
    ToolStripMenu menu = new ToolStripMenu();
    AttachCommonFunctionality(menu);
    Items.Add(menu);

    ContextMenuStrip rightClick = new ContextMenuStrip();
    AttachCommonFunctionality(rightClick);
    this.ContextMenu = rightClick;
    //etc...
}

private void AttachCommonFuntionality(Control c)
{
    c.Items.Add(_item1);
    c.Items.Add(_item2);
    //etc...

    c.OnClick += _myCommonAction;
    //etc...
}
```